# How can I add two 16 bit numbers in assembly language in microprocessor 8086

Tags: assembly, x86

Hey I am using window 7 x86. I want to add two 16 bit numbers.

When I add `3+3` its answer is correct but when I add `7+7` it's not working. And I want to add two numbers like `75+75` its answer should be 150.

What is its procedure please tell me. Thanx in advance

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
num db 9 dup(0)
result dw 9 dup (0)
.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ah, 1
int 21h    ; get input from user
mov num, al    ; store in the array 

int 21h              ;get 2nd number from user
mov num+1, al        ;store in the array at num[1] index

mov al, num          ;mov number into al
add dl, num+1        ;add num[1] in the num which is in dl

sub dl, 48           ; subract from assci so it become number 0 ~ 9

mov ah, 2            ; output
int 21h

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: 1. Assembly is not like high level languages so you should add comment for others to understand your code easily. 2. There's no other addition in your code except `add dl, num+1`, and this is a 8-bit addition. There's no loop either. Also, you're actually adding dl with dl itself. If you want to double the value, use `add dx, dx`, `shl dx, 2` or `lea dx, [dx+dx]`

Comment: now post is commented

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to add 2 16-bit numbers on 8086:

```
.model small
.data
a db "Enter the first number$"
b db "Enter the second number$"
c db "The sum is: $"
d db 00h

.code
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov dx,offset a
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov bh,al
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov bl,al

mov dx,offset b
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov ch,al
mov ah,01h
int 21h  
mov cl,al
add al,bl
mov ah,00h
aaa
add bh,ah
add bh,ch
mov d,al
mov al,bh
mov ah,00h
aaa
mov bx,ax
add bx,3030h

mov dx,offset c
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov dl,bh
mov ah,02h
int 21h
mov dl,bl
mov ah,02h
int 21h
mov dl,d
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h
end start
```

The trick here lies in using 'aaa' command to unpack the digits.

Answer (score 1):

With `INT 21h Fn 02` you can get only one character. To receive more characters you must create a tricky loop. But there is another function in DOS: `INT 21h Fn 0Ah`. For conversion of a number greater than one digit you need two conversion routines - surely detailed explained in your schoolbook. Take a look at my example:

```
.MODEL small
.386

.STACK 1000h

.data

    num label
        max db len
        real db 0
        buf db 6 dup(0)             ; Input (5 digits) + CR
        len = $-buf

    db 'ENDE'

    int1 dw 0
    int2 dw 0
    int3 dw 0

    result db 6 dup ('$')           ; Output (5 digits) + CR

.code

main PROC

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax                       ; Init DS
    mov es,ax                       ; Init ES for stosb

    mov dx, OFFSET num
    mov ah, 0Ah                     ; Input a string
    int 21h

    call dec2int
    mov [int1], ax

    mov dl, 0Ah                     ; Linefeed
    mov ah, 02h                     ; Cooked Output one character
    int 21h

    mov dx, OFFSET num
    mov ah, 0Ah                     ; Input a string
    int 21h

    call dec2int
    mov [int2], ax

    mov ax, [int1]                  ; first number
    add ax, [int2]                  ; add with second number
    mov [int3], ax                  ; Store result in [int3]

    mov dl, 0Ah                     ; Linefeed
    mov ah, 02h                     ; Cooked Output one character
    int 21h

    mov di, OFFSET result           ; [ES:DI] = receives the result string
    mov ax, [int3]                  ; AX = result from addition
    call int2dec
    mov dx, OFFSET result
    mov ah, 09h                     ; Output until '$'
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h                   ; Exit(0)
    int 21h

main ENDP

dec2int PROC
    xor ax, ax                      ; AX receives the result
    mov si, OFFSET buf
    movzx cx, byte ptr [real]       ; Number of characters
    test cx, cx                     ; Buffer empty?
    jz _Ret                         ; yes: return with AX=0

    _Loop:                          ; Repeat: AX = AX * 10 + DX
        imul ax, 10
        mov dl, byte ptr [si]
        and dx, 000Fh               ; Convert ASCII to integer
        add ax, dx
        inc si
        loop _Loop

    _Ret:
    ret
dec2int ENDP

int2dec PROC
    mov bx, 10                      ; Base 10 -> divisor
    xor cx, cx                      ; CX=0 (number of digits)
  Loop_1:
    xor dx, dx                      ; No DX for division
    div bx                          ; AX = DX:AX / BX   Remainder DX
    push dx                         ; Push remainder for LIFO in Loop_2
    add cl, 1                       ; Equivalent to 'inc cl'
    or  ax, ax                      ; AX = 0?
    jnz Loop_1                      ; No: once more
  Loop_2:
    pop ax                          ; Get back pushed digits
    or ax, 00110000b                ; Conversion to ASCII
    stosb                           ; Store only AL to [ES:DI] (DI is a pointer to a string)
    loop Loop_2                     ; Until there are no digits left
    mov al, '$'                     ; Termination character for 'int 21h fn 09h'
    stosb                           ; Store AL
    ret
int2dec ENDP

END main
```