# Simple fibonacci printer in 8086 assemlby

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I've been starting to learn assembly a few days ago and I'm trying to make a program to print the *fibonacci series* for up to 5 characters, but my code prints out weird characters

I thought it's because of the ASCII conversion system, but even when I add the value 48 to the number it's still not correct.

```
.model small 
.data
  lastFib DB 0
.code
  main PROC
    mov cx,5
    mov dl,48
  loopy: 
    add dl,lastFib 
    mov ah,2h          
    int 21h
    mov lastFib,dl   
    loop loopy 
  ENDP
end main
```

Comment: I am too lazy to write a proper answer. Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23181254/3512216

Comment: use some debugger to see yourself what values are in registers..

Comment: There isn't an MS-DOS or BIOS function to output a number, only a single character or a string. So unless you make or borrow one and then output the digit string, you are limited to the single digits `0` to `9`. Luckily, the first five Fibonacci terms are all single digit. So start with `0` and `1` (or `1` and `1` in some definitions), and after the fifth term, add `48` and output the character.

Comment: Anyway you aren't even generating a Fibonacci sequence, you are doubling the number in each loop iteration. I suggest you write a simple C code first, to get the algorithm right, and then implement that in assembler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but my code prints out weird characters

Adding 48 is only needed to output the (small) number as a **character**. You mustn't allow this addition of 48 to tamper with your calculations of the fibonacci numbers. In below code I add 48 just before calling DOS, and immediately after, I take the addition back.

Currently your code does not calculate any fibonacci number at all. The basic scheme would be:

```
xchg dl, lastFib   ; Exchange current with previous
add  dl, lastFib   ; Add previous to current
```

There are 6 single digit fibonacci numbers: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8.
By *outputting **before** calculating the next fibonacci number*, the below code manages to print all 6 numbers in one loop. A 7th number (13) is calculated but never displayed.

```
.model small 
.data
  lastFib DB 0       ;previous
.code
  main PROC
    mov  cx, 6
    mov  dl, 1       ;current
  loopy:
    add  dl, 48      ;make character
    mov  ah, 02h
    int  21h
    sub  dl, 48      ;take back
    xchg dl, lastFib
    add  dl, lastFib
    loop loopy
  ENDP
end main
```

### Why don't we optimize the code a bit?

- With plenty registers available, there's no reason to keep that *lastFib* variable in memory!
- We could avoid the slow `loop` instruction as well as [the costly `xchg` with memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458023/simple-fibonacci-printer-in-8086-assemlby/51466354?noredirect=1#comment106365145_51466354).
- Selecting a register other than `DL` for the current fibonacci number will shave off the extra 'take back' instruction.

None of these changes will speed up **this code** because of the DOS api call involved. Nonetheless there're all good optimizations for when there's no such system call present.

```
.model small 
.code
  main PROC
    xor  cx, cx      ; Previous
    mov  bx, 1       ; Current
  loopy:
    lea  dx, [bx+48] ; Make character in DL
    mov  ah, 02h     ; DOS.PrintChar
    int  21h
    xchg bx, cx
    add  bx, cx
    cmp  bx, 10
    jb   loopy
  ENDP
end main
```

This time the loop is only continued for as long as the number in `BX` remains single digit.

Comment: Avoiding `loop` is pretty much pointless if you're going to `xchg` with memory!  (full barrier on 386 and later, the same CPUs where `loop` started to be slow.)  Maybe you want `xadd dl, dh` or something.  (Yes, [xadd](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xadd) works with register operands.  It's not exactly fast either, but is compact)

Comment: IMO I'd remove the middle version; making those changes one at a time just bloats the answer.  Also, using another register might be better so you could just do a more normal `mov`/`add` or `lea` to get `f + '0'` into DL for printing, instead of add/sub.  I guess the critical path latency isn't going to matter when you're printing inside the loop, though.

Comment: nice, good example of an efficient way to do single-digit Fibonacci.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your assembler (MASM?), but the code is fairly simple and should work.

A easy way to print a number in `C` and other languages is to use recursive functions. But with assembly this is difficult. Here I calculate the number of digits first, and then print the digits one by one. Since `AX` holds at most 5 digits, doing it without a loop is simple and actually better.

```
.model small 
.data

.code
main PROC
            mov     di, 0       ; Fibonacci(n-1); n = 1
            mov     si, 1       ; Fibonacci(n);   n = 1

loopA:      mov     ax, si      ; prepare for counting digits
            xor     cx, cx      ; cx will be number of digits
            mov     bx, 10      ; print as decimal
loopDigit:  xor     dx, dx      ; dx:ax is the dividend
            div     bx
            inc     cx
            or      ax, ax      ; test if the quotient is 0
            jnz     loopDigit
            ; cx should be the number of digit

            mov     bp, si      ; the number to be printed
            cmp     cx, 5       ; test if there are 5 digits
            jb      digit4
            mov     ax, bp      ; get the number
            mov     bx, 10000
            div     bx
            mov     bp, dx      ; the next number to be printed
            mov     dl, al      ; the quotient, current digit
            add     dl, 48      ; convert to ASCII
            mov     ah, 2h
            int     21h
digit4:     cmp     cx, 4       ; test if there are 4 or more digits
            jb      digit3
            mov     ax, bp      ; get the number
            mov     bx, 1000
            div     bx
            mov     bp, dx      ; the next number to be printed
            mov     dl, al      ; the quotient, current digit
            add     dl, 48      ; convert to ASCII
            mov     ah, 2h
            int     21h
digit3:     cmp     cx, 3       ; test if there are 4 or more digits
            jb      digit2
            mov     ax, bp      ; get the number
            mov     bx, 100
            div     bx
            mov     bp, dx      ; the next number to be printed
            mov     dl, al      ; the quotient, current digit
            add     dl, 48      ; convert to ASCII
            mov     ah, 2h
            int     21h
digit2:     cmp     cx, 2       ; test if there are 4 or more digits
            jb      digit1
            mov     ax, bp      ; get the number
            mov     bx, 10
            div     bx
            mov     bp, dx      ; the next number to be printed
            mov     dl, al      ; the quotient, current digit
            add     dl, 48      ; convert to ASCII
            mov     ah, 2h
            int     21h
digit1:     mov     dx, bp      ; always need to print the last digit
            add     dl, 48      ; convert to ASCII
            mov     ah, 2h
            int     21h

            add     di, si      ; Fibonacci(n) = Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2)
            jc      done        ; overflow, done!
            xchg    di, si      ; to keep them in order; si = F(n); di = F(n-1)
            jmp     loopA
done:
ENDP
end main
```

It is more complicated to print it with loop, as we need to calculate the divisor (`cx` below) before using it and adjust it in each loop:

```
.model small 
.data
.code
main PROC
            mov     di, 0       ; Fibonacci(n-1); n = 1
            mov     si, 1       ; Fibonacci(n);   n = 1

            mov     cx, 1       ; 10^n_digits
loopA:      mov     ax, si      ; prepare for counting digits
            mov     bx, 10      ; print as decimal
loopDigit:  xchg    ax, cx      ; calculate 10^n_digits
            mul     bx
            xchg    cx, ax
            xor     dx, dx      ; can be omitted, dx should be 0
            div     bx
            or      ax, ax      ; test if the quotient is 0
            jnz     loopDigit

            mov     bx, si
            mov     bp, 10
loopPrint:  mov     ax, cx      ; need to divide cx by 10 first
            xor     dx, dx
            div     bp
            mov     cx, ax
            mov     ax, bx      ; get the number
            xor     dx, dx
            div     cx
            mov     bx, dx      ; the next number to be printed
            mov     dl, al      ; the quotient, current digit
            add     dl, 48      ; convert to ASCII
            mov     ah, 2h
            int     21h
            cmp     cx, 1       ; should end?
            jnz     loopPrint

            add     di, si      ; Fibonacci(n) = Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2)
            jc      done        ; overflow, done!
            xchg    di, si      ; to keep them in order; si = F(n); di = F(n-1)
            jmp     loopA
done:
ENDP
end main
```