# how to print the first 20 elements in the Fibonacci series (assembly 8086)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am trying to write a code that runs a loop that print the first 20 numbers in the Fibonacci series. But I dont know how can I solve it and I tried many ways.

```
org 100h

mov ax, 0
mov bx, 1
mov cx, 20

start:        

call print_num ; this is function that print the value that inside ax register
PRINTN ; this is print new line
mov dx, ax
add ax, bx   
loop start
   
mov ah, 0

int 16h
ret 


include magshimim.inc ; this is a private library
```

Someone know how can I do this?

Comment: Try adding `mov bx, dx` before the `loop` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

### Depends on how we want the sequence to start.

Even Fibonacci himself started his sequence from 1,2,3,5,8,...
See the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

---

Your code after applying the correction suggested by @ecm:

```
org 100h

  mov ax, 0
  mov bx, 1
  mov cx, 20
start:        
  call print_num
  PRINTN
  mov dx, ax
  add ax, bx   
  MOV BX, DX
  loop start
  mov ah, 0
  int 16h
  ret 

include magshimim.inc
```

It will output:

> ```
> 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,...
> ```

Sometimes we don't want to start with the zero. Next code works that way:

```
org 100h

  mov  ax, 1
  xor  bx, bx
  mov  cx, 20
start:        
  call print_num
  PRINTN
  xchg ax, bx
  add  ax, bx   
  loop start
  mov  ah, 00h  ; BIOS.WaitKey
  int  16h      ; -> AX
  ret

include magshimim.inc
```

It will output:

> ```
> 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,...
> ```

Some more info about this in
[Simple fibonacci printer in 8086 assemlby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458023/simple-fibonacci-printer-in-8086-assemlby)